# Can't get Python objects to stop sharing a list

Tags: python

I know this is a somewhat common problem with Python, but I'm out of ideas. I made a little DOS pathfinder that relies on creating on creating and cloning 'finder' objects to go through the maze. Every new finder inherits the list of coordinates from the finder before it, and multiple finders are created at a branch. My issue is that they're all sharing the same list of coordinates and I do not know why.

At a branch, the finder object returns its current coordinate list and then new finders are made that all get that. I'm deep copying the list of coordinates before returning it in the 'explore' function and I've also tried iteratively making a brand new loop. For whatever reason, no matter what I do the coordinates list in ever finder object is all the same coordinates list. I also tried defining a new list as listvar before I pass it into the new finder and it still doesn't matter. And listvar even inherits the new coordinates as they are appended inside of the finders. I just don't understand.

```
import openpyxl
import copy
def readmap(filepath):
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
    map = []
    x = 1
    start = [0,0]
    while x <= 10:
        y = 10
        templist = []
        while y >= 1:
            templist.append(sheet_obj.cell(row = y, column = x).value)
            if sheet_obj.cell(row = y, column = x).value == 'S':
                start = [x-1,10-y]
            y -= 1
        map.append(templist)
        x += 1
    return [map,start]

def printmap():
    x = 9
    while x >= 0:
        y = 0
        temp = []
        while y <= 9:
            if map[y][x] is None:
                temp.append(' ')
            else:
                temp.append(map[y][x])
            y += 1
        print(temp)
        x -= 1

def lookaround(location):
    emptyspaces = []
    print('exploring from ' + str(location))
    print(map[location[0]][location[1]])
    if (location[0] == 0 or location[0] == 9 or location[1] == 0 or location[1] == 9) and map[location[0]][location[1]] is None:
        return('DONE')

    # right
    if(location[0] < 9):
        look = map[location[0] + 1][location[1]]
        if look == None:
            emptyspaces.append([location[0] + 1,location[1]])

    # left
    if (location[0] > 1):
        look = map[location[0] - 1][location[1]]
        if look == None:
            emptyspaces.append([location[0] - 1, location[1]])

    # up
    if (location[1] < 9):
        look = map[location[0]][location[1] + 1]
        if look == None:
            emptyspaces.append([location[0], location[1] + 1])

    # down
    if (location[1] > 1):
        look = map[location[0]][location[1] - 1]
        if look == None:
            emptyspaces.append([location[0], location[1] - 1])


    return emptyspaces

class Finder:
    def __init__(self, coordinates,location, name):
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.coordinates.append(location)
        self.location = location
        self.name = name

    def explore(self):
        print(self.name)
        empties = lookaround(self.location)
        if empties == 'DONE':
            return(['done',self.coordinates,[]])
        if(len(empties) == 0):
            map[self.location[0]][self.location[1]] = 'X'
            print('created an X at ' + str(self.location[0]) + ',' + str(self.location[1]))
            return(['dead',[],[]])
        if(len(empties) == 1):
            map[self.location[0]][self.location[1]] = 'X'
            print('created an X at ' + str(self.location[0]) + ',' + str(self.location[1]))
            self.location = [empties[0][0],empties[0][1]]
            self.coordinates.append([self.location[0],self.location[1]])
            return(['normal',[],[]])
        if (len(empties) > 1):
            map[self.location[0]][self.location[1]] = 'X'
            print('created an X at ' + str(self.location[0]) + ',' + str(self.location[1]))
            copy_list = copy.deepcopy(self.coordinates)
            return(['branch',copy_list,empties])

results = readmap('map.xlsx')
map = results[0]
print(map[0][2])
start = results[1]
print(start)
finders = []
deadlist = []
starter = Finder([],start, 1)
finders.append(starter)
done = False
while not done:
    printmap()
    print('test')
    for f in finders:
        if f not in deadlist:
            results = f.explore()
            if results[0] == 'done':
                done = True
                answer = results[1]
                for c in results[1]:
                    print(c)
                break

            if results[0] == 'branch':
                listvar = list(results[1])
                for new in results[2]:
                    newfinder = Finder(listvar,new, len(finders) + 1)
                    finders.append(newfinder)
                deadlist.append(f)

            if results[0] == 'dead':
                deadlist.append(f)

results = readmap('map.xlsx')
map = results[0]
for a in answer:
    map[a[0]][a[1]] = 'X'

printmap()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newfinder = Finder(copy.deepcopy(listvar),new, len(finders) + 1)
```

I figured it out. you have to deepcopy in the declaration of the new object, or you're passing the new object a reference to the list that exists in the main loop.